# How to use fade effect in jQuery preventing the content from disappearing?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm creating a dimmer plug-in and I would like to give it a nice fade transition. To dim the page when I use a background semi-transparent 'png' image and it works, but the issue is that when I give it the fade effect everything disappears when I would like to give that effect only to the background.

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){


// Hide shadow

jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');

jQuery(".custom-read-more-toggle").on("click", function() { 

if(jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background-image') == 'none' ) {
  jQuery(".shadow-class").css({background : 'url(/* PNG HERE*/)'}).fadeOut(1000);
 } else if (jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'url(/*PNG HERE*/)')){ 
jQuery(".shadow-class").css('background', 'none');
}

});

});
```

What can I do to prevent that everything disappears? Note that I've remove the fade functions attached inside if-else.

Comment: can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have that CSS class on something you shouldn't have. Check your body, or main wrapper, or whatever, for that .shadow-class byt we're all just gonna be guessing unless you provide more code, or Fiddle it. Can you provide a working prototype on Codepen or Fiddle or something?

With that said, you will want to stop using JS to check for CSS property state (background-image), and instead add and remove classes with JS, and just create CSS rules for the classes.

Last note, based on your problem, stop using .fadeOut and instead (again) just toggle CSS classes, one with opacity:0 and the other with opacity:1, and use a transition (ie. transition: opacity 1s;)

Feel me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are misinformed about how `opacity` works (and in turn `.fadeOut()`).  If you apply an `opacity` value to an element, it and all of it's children are affected by that value.  So setting `opacity:.5;` to the parent will set it and everything inside at half opacity.

If you had a solid background color you wanted to make translucent or transparent in a transition, you could use the `background-color:rgba();` property where the `rgba()` includes the comma separated values of the RGB color for the background and the A is the alpha, which works like opacity but will not affect other elements.

If you are working with a just one image, the transition to and from the image should work however if you want the image to be translucent, you'll need to create a second image, and apply the opacity to that image (in Photoshop for example) and then transition to that second image.